# Excel: Creating a buttong to save current version and reset cells

Tags: excel, vba

I currently use a printed out grid to document my work, but its a bit of a pain to search through and organize. I'd like to go digital, but want to find an easy 'Save current Version' and 'Reset form' option.

If that's is unclear, I want to make a button that will save the spreadsheet, exactly as it is at the time of click (using a name I enter in cell A1), then reset the contents of the spreadsheet.

They can be two separate buttons if needed, but that is the minimum requirement.

Comment: This should be pretty straightforward. What have you tried so far? Please post any code you have.  If you don't know where to start, turn on the Macro Recorder and save the document, then reset your cells, and stop the recorder. This will give you a nice skeleton to start with.  Then, search around for "save Excel with variable name" or something like that, and create a variable based on `A1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this before, and with a little planning can be accomplished through a recorded macro.

Steps:

1. Create 2 Worksheets, "Form" and "Data".
2. Design the form on the "Form" worksheet, and populate with sample data.
3. On the top row of the "Data" worksheet, create references to the fields you to record.
4. Now Go back to the "Form" worksheet. and start the macro recording.
5. Go to the "Data" worksheet, right click the row header below the reference row created in step 3 and select "Insert".
6. Right Click on the row header of the reference row created in step 3 and select "Copy".
7. Right Click on the row header of the newly insert row from step 5 and select "Paste Special > Values".
8. Go back to the "Form" worksheet and delete all the placeholder values.
9. Stop the macro recording and save.
10. Insert a button that points to the newly created macro.

You can also do this all with VBA, but for a simple task like this, the Record Macro function is perfect.

Comment: Happy to help, it is a pattern I use quite a bit, so I was happy to finally get to share it with some one.